# Javascript: the variable from [user-defined prototype] is not available

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, inheritance

I play javascript with the book *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*. I practice an example in section 6.2.6. the codes are listed below：

```
function creatPrototype(subType, superType) 
{
    function subTypePrototype(){};
    subTypePrototype.prototype = superType.prototype;
    subTypePrototype.constructor = subType;
    subTypePrototype.str = "say";
    return new subTypePrototype();
}

function Person(name, age) 
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.say = function(){
    writeln("bill say");
}


function itMan(name, age){
    Person.apply(this, arguments); 
}
itMan.prototype = creatPrototype(itMan, Person); 


var Bill = new itMan("bill", 25);

writeln(itMan.prototype.str);    //expect "say"
writeln(Person.prototype == itMan.prototype.prototype);   //expect true
Bill.say();  //expect "bill say"
```

the result is:

> undefined
>
> False
>
> bill say

**Why?**

1. itMan.prototype.str is suppose to "say"
2. Person.prototype *AND* itMan.prototype.prototype should point to a same object
3. Bill.say() run correctly, so the prototype chain is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think about which property belongs to the *constructor function* and which one belongs to the *instance*. `prototype` is a property of the function, but `constructor` and `str` should be both properties of the instance.

This should do it:

```
function createPrototype(subType, superType) 
{
    function subTypePrototype(){};
    subTypePrototype.prototype = superType.prototype;

    var newPrototype = new subTypePrototype();

    newPrototype.constructor = subType;
    newPrototype.str = "say";
    return newPrototype;
}
```

But, as you are also passong `subType`, you can actually assign the prototype directly:

```
function inherit(subType, superType) 
{
    function tconstr(){};
    tconstr.prototype = superType.prototype;

    subType.prototype = new tconstr();

    subType.prototype.constructor = subType;
    subType.prototype.str = "say";
}
```

and then just call it with

```
inherits(itMan, Person);
```

---

> Person.prototype AND itMan.prototype.prototype should point to a same object

Remember that `prototype` is a property of a **function**, not of objects. But `itMan.prototype` is a an object. You cannot access an objects prototype unless you explicitly refer to it (but I would not do so).

With ECMAScript 5, there is a way to get the prototype, using [`Object.getPrototypeOf` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf). This only works in newer browsers though.

Here is a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vg4j/) of your code.

Comment: You got the point. Your solution is similar to the original example from **the book**. _subTypePrototype.constructor_ and str may not be one part of the return value _new subTypePrototype()_ .

Answer (score 1):

There were some mistake with the code, try this code

```
function creatPrototype(subType, superType) 
{
    function subTypePrototype(){
    this.prototype = superType.prototype;
    this.constructor = subType;
    this.str = "say";
}


    return new subTypePrototype();
}

function Person(name, age) 
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.say = function(){
    document.writeln("bill say");
}


function itMan(name, age){
    Person.apply(this, arguments); 
}
itMan.prototype = creatPrototype(itMan, Person); 


var Bill = new itMan("bill", 25);

document.writeln(itMan.prototype.str);    //expect "say"

document.writeln(Person.prototype == itMan.prototype.prototype);   //expect true
Bill.prototype.say();  //expect "bill say"
```

In your code, you were not using `this` object so `itMAn` had no variable str, 
you were using
`subTypePrototype.constructor = subType;`
and `subTypePrototype.prototype = superType.prototype;`
therefore `Bill.say` was working and `Person.prototype == itMan.prototype.prototype` was not working.

Comment: Your approach is better, but assigning `prototype` and `constructor` to `this` is wrong.

Comment: Felix is right on this, is example show how to do it properly.

Comment: @felix thanx for poining out, you are correct, your method is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Prototype is a reserved keyword and you have to be very careful while using it
[Articles on prototype keyword](http://mrwhat.is/javascript-prototype-keyword.html)

You have several issues in your code.

Then within your createSubPrototype :

```
return new subTypePrototype();
```

You are creating a function and then you are returning the executed function result where you should return a pointer to your function like

```
return subTypePrototype;
```

But you should not create a function cause it seems you want to retrieve parent "prototype" :)

So indeed your code should look more like :

```
function createPrototype(subType, superType) 
{
  subTypePrototype = superType.prototype;
  subTypePrototype.constructor = subType; //- beware this is wrong !!!
  subTypePrototype.str = "say";
  return subTypePrototype;
}
```

Check the line I have marked as wrong, by doing so you are updating both sub & parent type

How to do it :
That being said if you want to extend an object I would advise you to use existing libs. (jQuery, Mootools, etc ). [Here a sample on how to do it properly](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/01/06/javascript-object-extension/)

Comment: So, you are telling him not to use prototype, and yet your link is to articles which show how to use the prototype keyword? There is nothing wrong with using prototype; in fact it's the proper way to achieve javascript inheritence (at least says Douglas Crockford http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).

Comment: I have to disappoint you, but `prototype` is not a reserved keyword: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.6.1

Comment: Your `creatPrototype` is not correct as well. Any property you assign to `subTypePrototype` will also be assigned to `superType.prototype`. This is not a good approach.

Comment: @RoccoC5 : Thanks for pointing this out. You are right, I wrote this perhaps too quickly and my English was not that correct. I have update  the post accordingly.

Comment: @Felix : From my understanding it is, cause if you are computing your own prototype content on a class I doubt this object will work properly ... but anyway please correct me if I am wrong.
Sure my sample is not correct but it was just to explain that the function usage was not that efficient this way. Then I provided deeper sample using the link.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with *computing your own prototype content on a class*. But it is like this: `prototype` is just a "normal" property of functions. It is special in a way that if you call a function with `new`, the object created with this will inherit from the functions prototype. But as long as this property references an object, it is fine. Extending a functions prototype is the only way to share properties between instances of this function.